# how to convert ie6 project to compatible of ie8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

I developed one project with compatible to ie6. now i want to convert that project to compatible of ie8 . what is the solution?

If any body know please let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure it has a valid `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration.

If this is missing, your page will be rendering in quirks mode. Quirks mode is not a good thing, even in IE6, but a lot of sites "written for IE6" use it.

Fixing this, and then fixing the resulting errors in IE6 will make the page generally work in later browsers.

There are lots of valid doctypes, but if you don't know which one to use, the best one to pick is the HTML5 doctype. Simply add the following to the beginning of every HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

There are still other things that may need tweaking, but that should sort out most of your layout gremlins.

More difficult issues will arise if your site is written to use features in IE6 which have been removed or restricted for security reasons in later versions of IE (and may not exist at all in other browsers).

The most common example is ActiveX controls.

You can still use ActiveX controls in IE8, but the browser makes it much harder. Over the years they have been found to have a lot of security issues, so Microsoft has added configuration settings to disable them, and warnings when you use them.

If your site uses ActiveX controls, you will probably need to configure the users' browsers individually to get it working. You should also consider getting rid of the ActiveX components entirely, although if they comprise an important part of your system this may be easier said than done.

Finally, you should make an effort to ensure that your updated site works not just in IE8, but also in IE9, and IE10 (preview version available now), otherwise you may find yourself going through this same excersise again in a fairly short space of time. While you're at it, if you can get it to work in other browsers, that will also be a bonus.

There are a lot of other things that could be discussed from this question, but without more detailed knowledge of your system, it's hard to be any more specific. But I hope that helps.